React Test Error: ReferenceError: global is not defined
I'm newish to React and React Testing.  I've been taking an Udemy course that is a few years old and some things are out of date.  I got things updated with a lot of work.  I can build, I can start the app.  However, my once working tests now fail with this error:
Test suite failed to run
    ReferenceError: global is not defined
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:92:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expect/build/toThrowMatchers.js:10:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:35:48)

I ran a command I found in github about this issue:
$ npm list jest
react-testing@0.1.0 C:\Users\636309\Notes\React\ReactTesting\Udemy2HourCourseReactTesting\react-testingCopy
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ ├─┬ jest-watch-typeahead@1.1.0
│ │ └── jest@27.5.1 deduped invalid: "^29.0.0" from node_modules/ts-jest
│ └── jest@27.5.1 invalid: "^29.0.0" from node_modules/ts-jest
└─┬ ts-jest@29.2.4
  └── jest@27.5.1 deduped invalid: "^29.0.0" from node_modules/ts-jest

npm error code ELSPROBLEMS
npm error invalid: jest@27.5.1 C:\Users\steve\Notes\React\ReactTesting\Udemy2HourCourseReactTesting\react-testingCopy\node_modules\jest
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\development\npmCache\_logs\2024-08-10T03_18_02_069Z-debug-0.log

Here is a copy of my package.json:
{
  "name": "react-testing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^10.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.1.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.3",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "levenary": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "ts-jest": "^29.2.4",
    "typescript": "~5.5.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}",
      "!src/serviceWorker.ts",
      "!src/index.tsx",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
  }
}

Any clues?

You got errors after installing "jest-environment-jsdom": "^27.0.6" because you're using the jest version 29 and installing the v27 for jest-environment-jsdom. BTW, what's your node version?

Node.js v22.5.1.

Which versions of each should I be using?

jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen was used to make jsdom 16 available in jest 25 (which shipped with jsdom). Since you are using a more recent version of jest you should not need this package. Try uninstalling it and installing jest-environment-jsdom. You'll have to add "testEnvironment": "jsdom" in the jest configuration in package.json.

would you please upload your sample on codesandbox.io, because it's really help to find issue easier and faster

I'm newish to React.  The default app generated many files.  Which ones would I need to upload to codesandbox?

Add this to you App.js typeof global === 'undefined' ? global = window : null; and let me know.


Jest v26 and later ship with JSDOM@16, so there's no reason to use this package anymore.

[Source]
You are using 27 version of Jest, so you no longer need the jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen package.
If you replace your package.json file with this below and then run yarn install or npm install, everything should work. I've also tested it. ( after runing npm test the ReferenceError: global is not defined error disappeared )
for resolving the error regarding npm list jest:
it because your jest version is outdated ( 27.5.1 ) for current ts-jest, so you need to update package.json and add  "jest": "^29.7.0", to the devDependencies or run yarn add --dev jest on the project directory
I've try with the second solution and it works
macbook@Macbooks-MacBook-Air react-testing % npm list jest

    react-testing@0.1.0 /Users/macbook/Desktop/test/react-testing
    ├── jest@29.7.0
    ├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
    │ ├─┬ jest-watch-typeahead@1.1.0
    │ │ └── jest@27.5.1
    │ └── jest@27.5.1
    └─┬ ts-jest@29.2.4
      └── jest@29.7.0 deduped

package.json
{
  "name": "react-testing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^10.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.1.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.3",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "levenary": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
     "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.2.4",
    "typescript": "~5.5.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom",
    "coverage": "yarn test --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}",
      "!src/serviceWorker.ts",
      "!src/index.tsx",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
  }
}


Best answer yet.  Sadly, I'm still getting the same errors.  I even tried it after deleting my node_modules directory and running yarn install again.  No change.  I updated my post to display the new package.json I am using.  I also reran "npm list jest" and got much the same output from that as well.

Have you try 'npm test' or 'yarn test' command?

I've run yarn test and I've seen that the global is not defined resolved,  but after I run the npm list jest I have seen same error, then I run yarn add --dev jest or npm install --save-dev jest on the project directory and it resolved

I've updated the answer  ( and also package.json )

"yarn test" trying to "stay true" to the  Udemy course.

I added "jest": "^29.7.0", to my package.json and I then ran  yarn add --dev jest.
I finally got rid of that global is not defined  error message when running yarn test.
Thank you. It worked.

The issue stems from conflicting Jest versions and an outdated environment setup. Your react-scripts relies on Jest 27, while ts-jest expects Jest 29, causing errors. Additionally, the use of jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen might be unnecessary, leading to environment issues like the global is not defined error. To resolve this, align all Jest-related dependencies to compatible versions, update to the latest jest-environment-jsdom, and clean-install your node modules. This should stabilize your testing environment and fix the error.
